# How to read the encrypted passwords stored in database from php?

Tags: php, mysql, hash, passwords

I have a **users** table in which I have encrypted passwords for all users using password() function in mysql. There are 3 columns (**ID**, **user_name**, **user_pass**). All passwords in **user_pass** column are encrypted.

I have a php code login application which verifies usernames/passwords from the **users** table.

**Problem Statement:**

I am wondering what changes I should make in the php code **(especially at Line C)** above so that it can read the encrypted passwords present in the users table. 
After I have encypted the passwords, its not reading anything at Line C.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/210771/discussion-on-question-by-flash-how-to-read-the-encrypted-passwords-stored-in-da).

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because either the passwords are hashed (and thus the premise is invalid, and you're asking for the impossible) or someone made a horrible design mistake that we shouldn't encourage. Don't encrypt passwords, hash them with a password hashing function (i.e. Argon2id or bcrypt).